# Duplicate data store in database PYTHON

Tags: python, python-2.7

My current python script:

```
import ftplib
import hashlib
import httplib
import pytz
from datetime import datetime
import urllib
from pytz import timezone
import os.path, time
import glob

def ftphttp(cam_name):

  for image in glob.glob(os.path.join('/tmp/image/*.png')):

    ts = os.path.getmtime(image) 
    dt = datetime.fromtimestamp(ts, pytz.utc)
    timeZone= timezone('Asia/Singapore')
    localtime = dt.astimezone(timeZone).isoformat()
    camid = cam_name(cam_name)
    tscam = camid + localtime
    ftp = ftplib.FTP('10.217.137.121','kevin403','S$ip1234')
    ftp.cwd('/var/www/html/image')

    m=hashlib.md5()
    m.update(tscam)
    dd=m.hexdigest()
    x = httplib.HTTPConnection('10.217.137.121', 8086)
    x.connect()
    f = {'ts' : localtime}
    x.request('GET','/camera/store?fn='+dd+'&'+urllib.urlencode(f)+'&cam='+cam_name(cam_name))

    y = x.getresponse()
    z=y.read()
    x.close()
    with open(image, 'rb') as file:
      ftp.storbinary('STOR '+dd+ '.png', file)

    ftp.quit()
```

Right now I'm able to send multiple files into another folder but the data that is store in the database is duplicated. Like example, when i store 3 files into the folder and then my database stored 6 data via httplib. Anybody got any ideas why the data is duplicated? HELP needed!